# Highcharts variable radius pie chart- Outer circle

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have implemented a Highchart.js Variable pie chart in my application. I need show outer circle / border to the whole chart, not to the individual slices, so that we can easily see how much of the slice is filled completely or partially.

I tried borderWidth, lineWidth etc, but no luck. Is there any way to implement the same? Need the output somewhat like the image.

[image: desired output like this]

Comment: Please, share the codes you tried.

Comment: Hello, thank for your comment. I found a way to achieve the desired output. I did it using empty pie circle as a base and added my main data series above it.

Comment: If you found a solution you can write up an answer to the question and potentially get credit for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can render all additional svg elements by using Highcharts.SVGRenderer class. Here you can find an example with the required circle:

```
events: {
  render: function() {
    const series = this.series[0],
      center = series.center,
      x = center[0] + this.plotLeft,
      y = center[1] + this.plotTop,
      r = Math.max(...series.radii);

    if (!this.customCircle) {
      this.customCircle = this.renderer.circle(
        x, y, r
      ).attr({
        stroke: 'red',
        zIndex: 3,
        fill: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        'stroke-width': 1
      }).add();
    } else {
      this.customCircle.attr({ x, y, r });
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r985mdkh/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#circle